# Ingesting data from Spark to Elasticsearch with index template

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, spark-streaming

In our existing design we are using logstash to fetch data from Kafka (JSON) and put it in ElasticSearch.

We are also using index template mapping while inserting data from logstash to ES and this could be done by setting 'template' property of ES output plugin of logstash, e.g.,

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    template => "elasticsearch-template.json", //template file path
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    template_overwrite => true
    manage_template => true
    codec=>plain
   }
}
```

elasticsearch-template.json looks like below,

```
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
   "settings" : {
       "index.refresh_interval" : "3s"
   },
   "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
       "dynamic_templates" : [ {
         "string_fields" : {
           "match" : "*",
           "match_mapping_type" : "string",
           "mapping" : {
             "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
             "fields" : {
               "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256, "doc_values":true}
              }
           }
        }
       } ],
      "properties" : {
         "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
         "geoip"  : {
            "type" : "object",
            "dynamic": true,
            "properties" : {
               "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
            }
          }
       }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now we are going to replace logstash with Apache Spark and I want to use similar kind of usage of index template in Spark while inserting data to ES.

I am using elasticsearch-spark_2.11 library for this implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: Follow these steps: 1) create index-template in elasticsearch as shown [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html#indices-templates) 2) as long as you index data into indices which prefix is `logstash-*` you will get same functionality mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked